# From intermediate code to Java bytecode (dragon book)

Tags: java, compiler-construction, bytecode

I'm enrolled in a compilers course, using the "dragon book" as textbook. It gives instructions on how to convert the intermediate code generated by its compiler to an object language, assembly.

My question is: where can I find instructions to convert an intermediate code in the 3-address format to java bytecode, for the same grammar used in the book?

Textbook site: http://dragonbook.stanford.edu/index.html#courses

Comment: Unless you must invent your own, you could target [Jasmin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasmin/).

Comment: It is not necesary to invent one, but I think Jasmin converts Java source code to bytecode. But the language studied on dragon book is not java. At the end of page (http://dragonbook.stanford.edu/), if you download the source code, the readme file describes the grammar used in the language.

Comment: Jasmin converts an *assembly language* to bytecode. Not Java source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know how to create a binary Java classfile yourself, there's no better resource than the official [JVM specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/index.html).

If you want to write a classfile in a human readable textual format, there are various assemblers available: [Krakatau](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau), [Jasmin](https://github.com/Sable/jasmin), and [Lilac](http://ehc.ac/p/lilac/wiki/Q%20%26%20A/?version=7) among others. Note that Jasmin is old and largely unmaintained, though the Sable Research Group maintains a fork of it for use with their own tools.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a translator that takes the three-address intermediate code, generated by the Dragon Book implementation of the front end of a compiler, and converts it to a Java bytecodes with a syntax similar to [Jasmin](https://github.com/Sable/jasmin). Then it uses [Krakatau](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau) to assemble it into a classfile executable through the JVM.

You can check my implementation at [https://github.com/joaofbsm/smallL/tree/master/code/translator](https://github.com/joaofbsm/smallL).